# Theres a way to query on hibernate without generate SQLs?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I need to query on my database (postgres) like this:

Entity:

```
class Cat{
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

main class:

```
int [] idCats = {1,2,7,5,8,4,9,10,12,14};

for(int id : idCats){ 
    Cat cat = session.load(Cat,id);
    (do something with cat, according your name)
}
```

But, this approach generates to many sqls. Considering i'll search almost all ids, there's a
way to bring all objects e search on it using criteria. Without implement by myself.

Comment: List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class).list(). But dont use it for large dataset. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

Comment: You want to execute queries: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying

Comment: @bgth , i'm already using like this, I implemented  a embedded "for" that iterates over the list of cats, and comparing manually the ids  . I would like to cache all objects into memory using just one select, and use criteria properties to find an especific object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the second level cache feature of hibernate. But if your application is simple and you just want to fetch a cat with its id, then store the result of the query in a hashmap like

```
Map<Integer, Cat> mapCats = new HashMap<Integer, Cat>();
```

You can use the for loop to iterate over the list from DB.

```
Map<Integer, Cat> mapCats = new HashMap<Integer, Cat>();
for(Cat oneCat: listCats) { 
    mapCats.put(oneCat.id, oneCat);
}
```

Then retrieve using 
    mapCats.get(catid);

Comment: I really needed to use criteria. I was searching about second level cache and query cache, and looks like it works. This link explain all [http://www.coderanch.com/t/526101/ORM/databases/Relation-Hibernate-Query-Cache-Level](http://www.coderanch.com/t/526101/ORM/databases/Relation-Hibernate-Query-Cache-Level). Thanks for your supporting